# Как можно сравнить цвет в матрице?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я создал матрицу размером 5 на 5 со случайными цветами, но не могу понять как сравнить близ стоящие клетки во время отрисовки матрицы, а также при нажатии на клетку, чтобы цвета не сливались. То есть слева, справа, сверху и снизу цвета не должны повторяться. При этом нужно использовать чистый JS. Вот мой код:

```js
const MATRIX_SIZE = 5;
const ELEMENT_SIZE = 40;

const rootNode = document.getElementById("app");

const getRandomColor = () => {
  const colors = [
    "black",
    "blue",
    "red",
    "magenta",
    "green",
    "cyan",
    "yellow",
    "white"
  ];
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
};

const usedColors = Array.from({
  length: MATRIX_SIZE
}, (_, i) => []);

const getNextColor = (useColors, row, col) => {
  let nextColor = getRandomColor();
  let prevColor;
  while (
    (useColors[row - 1] || [])[col] === nextColor ||
    (useColors[row + 1] || [])[col] === nextColor ||
    useColors[row][col - 1] === nextColor ||
    useColors[row][col + 1] === nextColor ||
    useColors[row][col] === nextColor ||
    prevColor === nextColor
  ) {
    prevColor = nextColor;
    nextColor = getRandomColor();
  }
  useColors[row].length < MATRIX_SIZE ?
    useColors[row].push(nextColor) :
    (useColors[row][col] = nextColor);
  return nextColor;
};

for (let row = 0; row < MATRIX_SIZE; row++) {
  for (let col = 0; col < MATRIX_SIZE; col++) {
    const square = document.createElement("div");
    square.style.cssText = `
      position: absolute;
      width: ${ELEMENT_SIZE}px;
      height: ${ELEMENT_SIZE}px;
      left: ${ELEMENT_SIZE * col}px;
      top: ${ELEMENT_SIZE * row}px;
      background-color: ${getNextColor(usedColors, row, col)}
    `;

    square.setAttribute("data-row", row);
    square.setAttribute("data-col", col);

    rootNode.append(square);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  const square = evt.target.closest("[data-row]");
  if (square) {
    const {
      row,
      col
    } = square.dataset;
    square.style.backgroundColor = getNextColor(usedColors, row, col);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>color matrix</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="src/index.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**UPD:**

Получилось сгенерировать матрицу где рядом стоящие цвета отличаются, но при клике, цвета с ячейками справа и снизу от той которую нажал иногда совпадают. Код подправил

Comment: При клике тоже не должен попадаться цвет, который рядом? Или при клике без разницы?

Comment: @EzioMercer по клику тоже не должен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю такой алгоритм:

```js
let matrixCount = 0;

const colors = [
  'black',
  'blue',
  'red',
  'magenta',
  'green',
  'cyan',
  'yellow',
  'white'
];

const getRandColor = () => colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

const getColorForCell = (rowNum, cellNum, matrix, currentColor) => {
  const nearestCellsBgColors = new Set([
    matrix?.[rowNum]?.[cellNum - 1],
    matrix?.[rowNum]?.[cellNum + 1],
    matrix?.[rowNum - 1]?.[cellNum],
    matrix?.[rowNum + 1]?.[cellNum]
  ].map(nearestCell => nearestCell?.style.backgroundColor || ''));

  nearestCellsBgColors.add(currentColor);

  while (true) {
    const bgColor = getRandColor();
    
    if (nearestCellsBgColors.has(bgColor)) continue;
    
    return bgColor;
  };
}

const createCellDiv = (rowNum, cellNum, matrix, matrixId) => {
  const cellDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const id = matrixId + '-' + rowNum + '-' + cellNum;

  cellDiv.className = 'cell cell-' + id;
  cellDiv.id = 'cell-' + id;
  cellDiv.style.backgroundColor = getColorForCell(rowNum, cellNum, matrix, '');

  cellDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {
    cellDiv.style.backgroundColor = getColorForCell(rowNum, cellNum, matrix, cellDiv.style.backgroundColor);
  });

  return cellDiv;
}

const createRowDiv = (rowNum, cellsNum, matrix, matrixId) => {
  const row = [];
  matrix.push(row);

  const rowDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const id = matrixId + '-' + rowNum;
  rowDiv.className = 'row row-' + id;
  rowDiv.id = 'row-' + id;

  for (let cellNum = 0; cellNum < cellsNum; ++cellNum) {
    const cell = createCellDiv(rowNum, cellNum, matrix, matrixCount);

    row.push(cell);
    rowDiv.appendChild(cell);
  }

  return rowDiv;
}

const createMatrix = (rowsNum, cellsNum, appendTo) => {
  const matrix = [];
  const matrixDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const matrixId = matrixCount;
  matrixDiv.className = 'matrix matrix-' + matrixId;
  matrixDiv.id = 'matrix-' + matrixId;

  for (let rowNum = 0; rowNum < rowsNum; ++rowNum) {
    const rowDiv = createRowDiv(rowNum, cellsNum, matrix, matrixId);

    matrixDiv.appendChild(rowDiv);
  }

  document.querySelector(appendTo).appendChild(matrixDiv);

  ++matrixCount;

  return {
    matrix,
    matrixDiv
  };
}

createMatrix(4, 8, '#app1');

createMatrix(4, 12, '#app2');
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
}

.cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app1"></div>
<br/>
<div id="app2"></div>
```

Comment: @DmitryBochok Изменил алгоритм. Теперь `getColorForCell` использует `new Set()` вместо массива, так намного быстрее и лаконичнее. Конечно, можно было и `array.map()` написать вручную чтобы было быстрее, но я посчитал что это в лишний раз нагромоздит код